# JS function causes shift of all elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is bottom bar, with CSS:

```
#bottom_nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px lightgray;
    background: url('http://localhost:3000/assets/font-try.jpg');
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "ProximaNova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;}
```

And on some AJAX actions there is Jquery function, to prevent elements сover bottom bar:

```
var $beforeBar= $('#bottom_nav').prev().offset().top;
    var $beforeBarPosition=$beforeBar+  $('#bottom_nav').prev().height();
 if($beforeBarPosition+50>=$('#bottom_nav').offset().top){

        $('#bottom_nav').css({'top':$(document).height()+100});
    }
```

Problem is that each time this function called, all elements on the page are shifted left slightly. Looks really ugly. If I disable function, no shift.

Also, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ3WF/)

**EDIT:**

Yeath, I got it, it is appearing window scroll panel on changing doc height.
Any solutions?

Comment: You may want to change all `<a>`s' `href` to `#`: http://jsfiddle.net/eQ3WF/1/ Edit: this effect might be caused by the scrollbar. If you change `+100px` to `-100px`, nothing is shifted.

Comment: There's just not enough info here to help. That JSFiddle doesn't seem to recreate the problem. Can you please kill the link URL's and test it in fiddle to see if you get the same results? Once you can duplicate it, we can help.

Comment: killed links, and yes, now it recreates problem, first click causes shift, here on left, on my host right, but doesn't matter

Comment: it looks like document also becomes wider, but I don't get why... or here it is jsfiddle effect

Comment: @Passerby, yes, it is scrollball. So anything can be done here?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Not unless you switch all document/body-related-percentages to some absolute value. The body's width can be affected by scrollbar, and you used something like `left:50%` which, when scrollbar appears, will be "pushed" left.

Comment: @Passerby, so I need to remove all %-based CSS to fix that? But how then I align divs in the middle of the all possible resolutions?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace Not "all" per say, just those who is _directly_ %-based on the width of body.

Comment: @Passerby, but as far as I can see, it is crucial to keep element in the middle of any screen. Only some complicated JS function works here? Something like taking new width in pixels, comparing it with old in pixels, and finding new persent margin to keep it on place?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace If you're already using percentage to target different resolutions, body resizing shouldn't make your webpage "looks really ugly"...One possible way is to make `body{overflow-y:scroll}` so the scrollbar always exists, no matter scrollable or not.

Comment: @Passerby, not the result, but this shift annoys me... ha-ha, may be the real user will never notice something like that. Yes, body overflow works. I think I will use it, don't see any negative side, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The shift is caused by this line:

```
$('#bottom_nav').css({'top':$(document).height()+100});
```

This is setting the top of the `#bottom_nav` element to 100 pixels past the end of the document... effectively increasing the height of the document by 170px (100px + the height of `#bottom_nav`). The next time this code is run, the value returned from `$(document).height()` is 170 higher... leading the page to expand in height by yet another 170px.

Comment: no, shift is horizontal, it is said "left". May be reading question before answering is good idea? Anyway, the reason is told by @passerby

Comment: The horizontal shift is caused by the scrollbar appearing, which is caused by the document length arbitrarily increasing. It's not clear (to me anyways) if the continually increasing length is intentional or not - and if it's not, then the real fix should address *that* rather than the side effects from the scrollbar appearing.